# Express js parsing array of objects from ajax post

Tags: node.js, express, post

I use Express for my Web Server, I have difficulties parsing incoming req.body data including an array of objects when handling a POST request.

Simplified server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var parseUrlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

router.post('/', parseUrlencoded, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Client code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: {
      idSomething: "idValue",
      arrayOfObjects: arrayOfObjectData
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
```

Data send from client is like this:

```
{ 
  idSomething: "idValue",
  arrayOfObjects: [
      { name: "SubObjectName1", qty: "1" }, 
      { name: "SubObjectName2", qty: "2" }
  ] 
}
```

but when i tried to access req.body from the server, the data structure is like this:

```
{ 
  idSomething: "idValue",
  'arrayOfObjects[0][name]': "SubObjectName1",
  'arrayOfObjects[0][qty]': "1",
  'arrayOfObjects[1][name]': "SubObjectName2",
  'arrayOfObjects[1][qty]': "2",
}
```

How to keep the data structure same in the server?

I tried to change body parser url encoded option to extended:true, but arrayOfObjects value becomes "[object object]" string value.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, but I got POST 400 bad request if I set the contentType to 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Comment: When I set the contentType and stringify the ajax data, I didn't get POST 400 bad request, but req.body.arrayOfObjects value becomes "[object Object]" string

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I did add app.use(bodyParser.json) before i set router.post......